# BasicStroke causes offcenter

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Changing the BasicStroke of a Graphics2D object to anything other than 1 causes it to not draw something on the center of a JPanel on startup.

This is a JPanel which is on a JFrame. This is the basic idea of my project, but it is not the entire thing.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(this.centered){
        this.myShape.setCenterX(this.getWidth()/2);
        this.myShape.setCenterY(this.getHeight()/2);
    }
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3)); //new BasicStroke(1) works fine
    g2.draw(this.myShape);
}
```

When you click and drag the myShape, myShape will immediately jump to the center. But when I initially compile and run it, paintComponent() paints it about a centimeter above the center of the screen if the stroke is not 1.

Is there something wrong with how I'm centering? I defined the MyShape class, so there could be an error there. Maybe the distance between the center and the drawing point is the space between JPanel and the top of the JFrame? How do I fix it?

Edit: added picture

http://s21.postimage.org/dfpmz73et/Untitled_1.png
The first shape is right where I want it. The other two are above where I want it. But it appears the displacement from the center are the same regardless of stroke size.

Comment: for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this is the normal behaviour for a shape. It assumes an outline of 1 pixel. So you need to change the center calculation when you know you are going to change the basic stroke size. Something like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3);
    int adjustment = stroke.getLineWidth() - 1;

    if(this.centered){
        this.myShape.setCenterX(this.getWidth() + adjustment / 2);
        this.myShape.setCenterY(this.getHeight() + adjustment / 2);
    }
    g2.setStroke(stroke);
    g2.draw(this.myShape);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The spacing seems independent of the stroke size (except 1), and it is much larger than a few pixels. Regardless of where I decide to put my shape, it will always be a few spaces above the correct coordinates. I have a picture to explain my dilemma.

Comment: A picture doesn't help. A SSCCE does, as mre has already suggested.